# How does the [draggable] component work in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am new to the angular 2 framework and on a whim I added `[draggable]` to my `<li>` element and it worked almost as intended. I am wondering where this is arising from. Also I would like each `<li>` element to move individually from each other. At the moment they are all dragging together. Any solutions to this?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'test-test',
  template: `
  <li
  style="user-select: none; list-style-type:none"
  *ngFor="let letter of list"
  [draggable]>
      {{letter}}
  </li> `,

})
export class Test {

  constructor(
  ) {}

  private list = ['a', 'b', 'c',]


}
```

Comment: `draggable` is a directive, try like this `*ngFor="let letter of list"><span [draggable]>{{letter}}</span></li>`. do you use [this](https://github.com/xieziyu/angular2-draggable) package?

Comment: Adding the span results in the same behaviour. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you need to read how to use the directive, which package do you use?

Comment: I am not using any specific package. I just assumed it was pre-built and somehow tied into the HTML draggable?

Comment: ah, I see, no, it's not angular specific, it's how HTML5 drag&drop works, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable)

Comment: Yeah thanks for that I found this example `draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged')"` so I guess I must translate that into something that will work with Angular

Comment: better use [this](https://github.com/xieziyu/angular2-draggable) package if you need to have that functionality

Comment: Unfortunately that package is still having the same effects so I will probably just make all my draggable elements in a SVG format and manipulate them through directives.... It's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?